# NASM - Возврат из собственного прерывания не работает

Tags: ассемблер, int, nasm, прерывания, qemu

Такие дела:

```
mov si, testInt
mov bx, 99h
call createCustomInterrupt

loop:
    int 99h
    jmp loop

testInt:
    ; рисуем мышкой
    iret
```

Если "iret" заменить на "jmp testInt", то все будет работать, но выйти будет невозможно.

Если "iret" оставить, то ничего не будет происходить. :(

```
createCustomInterrupt:
    shl bx, 2
    mov word [bx], si
    mov word [bx + 2], cs
    ret
```

Могу предоставить все нужное. Я перепробовал все что мог. Спасибо заранее за помощь.
NASM, QEMU.

Comment: Не очень помню, но разве в таблице прерываний первым идет не сегмент, а смещение вторым?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я смог решить проблему.

Возможно я не правильно понимаю как все это работает и объяснил это не правильно.

Но вот решение:

```
createCustomInterrupt:
    shl bx, 2
    mov ax, 0
    mov es, ax
    mov word [es:bx], si
    mov word [es:bx + 2], es ; <-- ноль (скорее всего потому, что код от нового прерывания в первом сегменте памяти)
    ret
```